# Using Eclipse Java formatter for PL/SQL

Tags: eclipse, plsql, code-formatting

Can we edit the Eclipse Java code formatter in such a way that most of its options work for PL/SQL code. If yes then, please let me know how is it possible and what all jars or Java files I need to change.

I know there are some formatters available for PL/SQL on web as well as in tools but I don't think any of them is as vast as Eclipse Java formatter.

Comment: The Eclipse Java editor and support code is very large, I don't think it would be practical to change it for another language.

Comment: I want to make a plugin kind of thing by either usng it or taking reference from it. Not sure what all jars are needed for this and where can  find source code for the same.

Comment: Look at Eclipse [xText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) for developing support for a new language. Install Eclipse SDK from `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3` (for 4.3) for Eclipse source.